# How to display rows based on similar cell values but different specific value in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet in excel populated with a column for direction (from and to), a column with train names, and another column for the destination the are coming from and going to. What I would like to do is figure out how to print specific rows on Sheet 2 that have the same train name but are going to and from different places. The following is an example of the spreadsheets I have:

```
Sheet 1
Direction         Train Name       Destination Name    

From               Acadian          Miami
To                 Acadian          Miami
From               Baynes           Miami
To                 Baynes           Orlando
From               Burns            Atlanta
To                 Burns            Atlanta
From               QCRoads          Atlanta
To                 QCRoads          Atlanta
From               Jones            Jackson
To                 Jones            Jackson
From               Cardinal         Nashville
To                 Cardinal         Cleveland
From               Chase            Cleveland
To                 Chase            Cleveland
From               Daniels          Cinncinati
To                 Daniels          Pittsburgh
From               Gathers          Los Angeles
To                 Gathers          San Diego

Sheet 2 (Example of Expected Result)
Direction         Train Name       Destination Name
From              Baynes           Miami
To                Baynes           Orlando
From               Cardinal         Nashville
To                 Cardinal         Cleveland
From               Daniels          Cinncinati
To                 Daniels          Pittsburgh
From               Gathers          Los Angeles
To                 Gathers          San Diego
```

Comment: Your requirements are not clear...

Comment: There are about 10,000 lines more than what it shown here, but I would like to display on Sheet 2 the rows that have the same train name but different destinations. So I was hoping for an example of a for loop to do this

Comment: @user3870159 could you extend your expected result columns (more examples) please

Comment: @pnuts The spreadsheet has too many lines (13,000) to do copy and paste

Comment: @MaciejLos I've edited the question. Please let me know if its still not clear

Comment: So, if a specific Train/Destination pair (ignoring Direction) exists on more than one row, then do not include that row in the results, but include everything else. Is that what you're aiming for?

Comment: @Joe yes, on Sheet 2 I want to only have the ones with the same train name but different destination names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can do this very simply in several steps:
in a helper column, i.e. `column D`, put down this formula to see if the row is duplicate or not:

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1)>1
```

then copy and drag and fill down until the end (the last row that contains your data);
then you will see `TRUE` and `FALSE` in front of each row: `TRUE` means the row is duplicate (according to your own rules) and `FALSE` means the row is not a duplicate.


Then, press `ctrl`+`F` to find all `TRUE` values in your sheet; then click on **FIND ALL** and it will list the cells found below the find window. Then click on the first row of the results and then hold the `shift` and click on the last row of the results. It will highlight the `TRUE` cells in your sheet. 

 Then, click on ***DELETE CELLS...*** and then in the *delete* pop-up window select **Entire row**. Bingo!